# Replace text between '=' and '?' on all occurences in URL string

Tags: bash, sed

Given this string:

`https://example.com?a=1&b=2`

I want to achieve the following:

`https://example.com?a=VALUE&b=VALUE`

This is how far I got:

`echo "https://example.com?a=1&b=2" | sed -e 's!=[^=]*&!=VALUE!'`

Gives:
`https://example.com?a=VALUEb=2`

I'm trying to figure out why "=" and "?" is so tricky to use and making the sed command(If it's the best option?) to handle as many wierd chars as possible as as values in the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> echo "https://example.com?a=1&b=2" | sed -e 's!=[^=]*&!=VALUE!'  
> https://example.com?a=VALUEb=2
> ```

- You are consuming the ampersand but not replacing it.
- You need to tell `sed` to repeat the replacement process more than once. Use a trailing `g` (for global) after closing the replacement specification.

```bsh
$ echo 'https://example.com?a=1&b=2' | sed -e 's!=[0-9]*!=VALUE!g'
https://example.com?a=VALUE&b=VALUE
```

---

> I'm trying to figure out why "=" and "?" is so tricky to use

Some characters act as either shell metacharacters or as metacharacters in regular expressions. Often both! They have a special meaning and not their ordinary meaning. Those characters you need to be careful with and either avoid them or escape them.

> making the sed command ... to handle as many [weird] chars as possible as as values in the query string.

Your approach of using a set consisting of the negation¹ of a terminator is a good one. You just made a mistake specifying the terminator. The end of the value you want to replace is indicated in your data by an ampersand (`&`) *not* by an equals-sign (`=`).

```bsh
$ echo 'https://example.com?a=1&b=2' | sed -e 's!=[^&]*!=VALUE!g'
https://example.com?a=VALUE&b=VALUE
```

---

¹ i.e. exclusion or whatever set-theory term is appropriate.